# How can I save larger amount of data on client machine in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm pretty new to js, and I started working on a machine learning project (without a database), and I want to store the brain on the client machine. So they could continue training their brain after returning to the page.

I tried cookies, but the data is too large (It can go up to *half a gigabyte*).

So I'm trying to find a way to keep the brain on the client.
If it helps the brain is basically an array of floats.

Comment: You can't store this much amount of data in client browser, you have too use some server side technology to store

Comment: It may be too much to ask of your users but another option would be to let them download a file and then upload it again when they come back.

Answer (score 0):

Array of floats need to be saved in a file and you might need to create your own structure
suggest to use xml file format